# How to pass properties to Java when using COMPSs

Tags: java, properties, environment-variables, distributed-computing, compss

I have a java application which is launched with a settings file passed as a property as follows:

```
java -DpropertiesFile=/path/to/properties/settings.properties -jar /path/to/jar/file.jar
```

I would like to know how/if I can pass this properties file when running my application with COMPSs framework.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently the only option is to set the environment variable _JAVA_OPTIONS. This is variable is read once the JVM is started.

In your example it would be:

```
export _JAVA_OPTIONS=-DpropertiesFile=/path/to/properties/settings.properties
```

NB: I used export as an example, use whatever command your system has to set environment variables.